# Boostrap collapse based on dynamic content loaded with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, accordion

I have a PHP page which generates multiple HTML tables that can have lot of lines.

```
+------+----------+
| user |   data   |
+------+----------+
| John |   xxxx   |
| John |   wwww   |
+------+----------+

+------+----------+
| user |   data   |
+------+----------+
| John |   yyyy   |
|  Rob |   zzzz   |
+------+----------+
```

The code looks like this

```
<?php
$prev_user = null;
$same_user = array();
while ($row = $res->fetch()) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $same_user[$id][0] = ($row['user'] == $prev_user) ? 1 : 0;
    ?>
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion_<?php echo $id ?>" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <table id="parr" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-nowrap">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>User</th>
               <th>Data</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td><?php echo $row['user'] ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $row['data'] ?></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <?php
   $prev_user = $row['user'];
}
?>
```

I would like know to collapse all the table which content the same user. In this example, the first table should be collapsed but not the second one.

While Jquery is executed after the content is loaded, I am wondering how to collapse the accordions where $same_user[id][0] equals 1.

Is it possible ?

Comment: You can either make a `<td style="display: none;"><?php echo $same_user[$id][0]; ?></td>` and use Javascript to collapse based on the value in there, or use pure Javascript and check for duplicate values in the table followed by a collapse.

Comment: id attribute has to be unique, so do not use it in a loop, use class instead

Comment: @csandreas1 And where exactly is OP looking for an id here? `$same_user[$id][0]` is returning a boolean